# Initramfs Issues

Tags: boot, kali-linux, windows, initramfs, fsck

Ok, so I'm running a full Kali distro from a USB. It's been working fine for years, with one previous initramfs error a while back that eventually went away after I stopped using the USB for a few months and then decided one day to try it again, and for some reason, it was working fine again.

I've hit an Initramfs issue again, in this instance saying that there are "94 Multiply-Claimed Block(s), shared with 1 File(s)".

I have a feeling my Windows 10 System, which I have installed to the Internal Drive, is to blame here, given what I've seen about it's idea of "Shutdown", although that's questionable.

Is there anything other than "fsck -f /dev/sda1" that I can do?

I've tried a longer method of manual mounting and booting, but fstab is showing sod all, which is another issue in itself.

I've also tried a number of different BIOS configurations, all to no avail. (Secure boot, legacy support, changing the boot order, manually selecting the boot device, etc).

The final key point is that these issues are all occurring on just one machine. I have two other computers that never have these issues.

Comment: `I have two other computers that never have these issues.` using the same USB or a different USB?

Comment: Try disabling hibernate/fastboot in Windows and holding Shift pressed while clicking shutdown.